# Actionscript problem in Dynamic TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Is possible to make a word as button within the dynamic textField in flash as3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000552.html

http://circlecube.com/2008/12/asfunction-texteventlink-tutorial-for-as3-flash-html-link-to-call-actionscript-function-tutorial/

This will helps u.

Answer (score 4):

Actually contrary to the other answers for this question, you can(kind of). By using an image tag in a string value for a `Textfield` object's `htmlText` property you can use a display object in the library as its source. Then you can use the `Textfield` object's `getImageReference()` method to get the image tag which has the display object from the library as its source. Heres an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var textField:TextField = new TextField()
            textField.width = 125;
            textField.height = 50;
            textField.htmlText = "This is a button <img id='myButton' src='MyButton'/> ";
            addChild(textField);

            var myButton:Sprite = textField.getImageReference("myButton") as Sprite;
            myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMyButtonClick);

        }// end function

        private function onMyButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("CLICKED!!!");

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

[image]

Comment: nicely done. html is always a little wonky but +1 for it working

Comment: @locrizak i agree, thats why I said "you can(kind of)". I do think that a button in a textfield can be achieved using the Text Layout Framework, but then again I'm not sure since I don't know that much about it.

Comment: @Taurayi Yeah I hear ya.. Haven't done flash in over a year (actionscript that is) but still remember most of it.

Comment: @Taurayi: If I found, I will update here. 
Thanks for your kind response.

Answer (score 2):

there's no addChild method in TextField. But you may cheat and place button over TextField (i.e. add it to container of a TextField).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no. You'd need to make a wrapper class/MovieClip containing both the button and text field.

Comment: I need a particular word as a button.

Comment: on a SimpleButton/UIButton (sorry forgot the class)?

Comment: UIButton!!! i don't know about that... 

I wants to assign word as button dynamically.