# How to "append" html text to text area in flex and flex mobile project to display sprite and text formatting

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, text-formatting, htmltext

I'm playing around with a messaging type of application. Does anyone know how, or of any tutorials on to "appending" html text to text areas in flex and flex mobile projects? And specifically how I could take that and basically "append" a sprite inline to the text when i need to? Something simple like:

**Username:**  some text right here!

So, Anyone have any experience "appending" sprites or simple text formatting? Thanks I'm realy stumped on how to solve these issues!

EDIT:
Based on an answer below it was sugguested that it's as simple as...

```
textAreaInstance.htmlText += "<b>Username:</b> some text right here!";
```

But its not. you can't do `.htmltext` with a text area. you can on a text field, so i tried

```
var TF:TextField = new TextField();
TF.width = 200;
TF.height = 200;
TF.htmlText="Image in textfield: <img src='http://upload.pusha.se/3/HittaTidning_75.jpg' hspace='0' vspace='0'>";

//then i go to my text area instance and tried to add it the way you suggested                  
text_area_instance.text += TF;
```

All this displays is `[object TextField]`

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to append html text, so you have to use += appending your html formatted stuff:

```
    textAreaInstance.htmlText += "<b>Username:</b> some text right here!";
```

You can embed display objects in TextArea in this way:

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        //display object class, what simply draws a recangle
        //you have to create a reference from this class, otherwise it won't work
        private var img:ImageStuff;


        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            txt.htmlText = "<img src='ImageStuff' width='16' height='16'/>";
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <mx:TextArea id="txt"/>
    <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
```

I don't know any way embedding display objects into spark TextArea.

Cheers

Comment: I was playing around with the first part of your answer. I dont think it's as simple as your putting it. Because first of all you cant do .html text like that with a text area. It needs to be a text field, look at my edit i'll show you what i tried based on your answer, but it just displays [object text field]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, so the TextArea in the mx package has htmlText property, thats why I used this in my example, because I could create a proper workaround with this component.

Comment: If you want to use s:TextArea, see it's textFlow property, and the TextFlowUtil class, but but you can't embed display objects to this component with <img>.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile this works (Worked for me):

Check this link
http://remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-html-text-to-a-flex-mobile-textarea

but use StyleableTextField instead of MobileTextField

Answer (score -1):

All you need is `htmlText` property of `TextField`:

```
tf.htmlText = "<b>Username:</b> some text right here!"
```

look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6e) for details.

As for embing sprite. Similar question was asked before. take a look at [Actionscript problem in Dynamic TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187831/actionscript-problem-in-dynamic-textfield/6187875#6187875)