# How to simply append a sprite into a text area?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textarea, sprite

How would I go about **appending** (not just changing the entire text area to this img, actually appending) a simple 25x25 image sprite into a text area in a flex project? using actionscript? (not mxml)

(it has to be a spark text area component, mostly because this is a flex mobile project and thats all thats optimized for mobile)

edit:
I guess I should have said this, i know html text is the way to go about it. But my real confusion lies with first it being a Sprite, so i dont have a url to link to. It's an actual sprite var (it would be a file sent over the network in bytes, and saved in a sprite object.) and then the second part where im lost is APPENDING it to the text inline, so it doesnt replace any of the text already in the text area, and will be scrollable in the text area.

also, remember im trying to append this to a SPARK TEXT AREA component. I know i could just make a text field instance and thats it, but i cant find any information about appending this to a text area

EDIT AGAIN:
SInce there was some confusion about the sprite im trying to append, this is how the image is being transmitted,

it's starting out as just a standard cameraphone image, then..

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(new File(imageURL), FileMode.READ);
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
fs.readBytes(bytes);
fs.close();
if (bytes == null) 
{
    trace("Image bytes is null!");

} 
else 
{
    var message:Object = new Object();
    message.type = "pic";
    message.bytes = bytes;
    netGroup.post(message);
    trace("Picture sent!");
}
```

Then i'm reciving it like this

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = false;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPicLoaded,false,0,true);
loader.loadBytes(message.bytes, loaderContext);
// add a new sprite to hold image
imageSprite = new Sprite();
imageSprite.addChild(loader);
```

So then finally I have the image in imageSprite... and that brings us to my main problem appending this image in a TEXT AERA spark component. With an end result that will have the look of a picture message sent on an android or iphone.

Comment: Possible duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6260417/532210

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before and it was a **pain**. The user would type and then click an image icon (like an emoticon) and it would "insert" into the text. All I was doing was breaking the currently focussed `TextField`, attaching the `BitmapImage`, and then start a new `TextField` at the end of the attached `BitmapImage`.

Steps:

- Create an array that stores your `TextField` and `BitmapImage` chunks.
- Every time you hear a *backspace* `KeyUp`, check to see if you are at the beginning of a `TextField`. If you're at the beginning of a `TextField` find that `TextField` in your array of chunks. If the previous chunk is a `BitmapImage` then find that `BitmapImage`, clear it along with the now empty `TextField` and then place the user's cursor at the end of the `TextField` chunk that was before the `BitmapImage`
- Revise and review. If you're *human*, there will be bugs.

You end up with what feels like a seamless `TextField` with "emoticon" integration. It's a hassle, but certainly works nice *when* you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using htmlText.
Dont know if this is the most propper way of going about but it works. :)

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var TF:TextField = new TextField();
this.TF.width = 200;
this.TF.height = 200;
this.TF.htmlText="Image in textfield: <img src='http://upload.pusha.se/3/HittaTidning_75.jpg' hspace='0' vspace='0'>";

this.addChild(this.TF);
```

Comment: I guess I should have said this, i know html text is the way to go about it. But my real confusion lies with first it being a Sprite, so i dont have a url to link to. It's an actual sprite var (it would be a file sent over the network in bytes, and saved in a sprite object.) and then the second part where im lost is APPENDING it to the text inline, so it doesnt replace any of the text already in the text area, and will be scrollable in the text area.

Comment: also, i need to append it to a TEXT AREA component. I know i could just make a text field instance and thats it, i need to append this htmltext to the TEXT AREA

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the sprite into image, if you are sure uploaded file is always an image.

Also, Did you see the spark component docs??

> "For performance reasons, it does not
>   support scrolling, selection, editing,
>   clickable hyperlinks, or images loaded
>   from URLs. If you need those
>   capabilities, please see the
>   RichEditableText class."

RichText http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/RichText.html

RichEditableText http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/RichEditableText.html

---

I don't do flex, but I think this is what you need?? So basically, adding a textflow inside the component is what is needed...

```
<s:RichEditableText id="richTxt" textAlign="justify" width="100%">
            <s:textFlow>
                <s:TextFlow>
                    <s:p>
                        <s:img source="@Embed(source='../assets/butterfly.gif')" height="100" width="100"/>
                    </s:p>
                </s:TextFlow>
            </s:textFlow>
        </s:RichEditableText>
```

From : [Adding images with TLF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff4.html)

Comment: i added another edit to give you a better idea of how im getting the image

Comment: I changed my answer, as it seems I diverted very much from your question earlier.

Comment: You can't use a rich text component in a Flex Mobile project, they only have the textArea component optimized for touch input. lol Adobe really is making this a headache.

Comment: I think you might need to add a custom component with an Image Holder & textbox for your work, then.